# Como deixar o @EditorFor desativado?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo um projeto de `CRUD` no ASP NET MVC na parte de editar as informações o código do time está sendo puxado do banco e está aparecendo no `@EditorFor` e gostaria de fazer com que ele não pudesse ser editado. como se fosse um `readonly` do `html`

Segue o código do campo:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.cd_time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cd_time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somente acrescente `readonly` na parte dos atributos:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.cd_time, new { 
    htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly="readonly" } 
})
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

---

- [InputExtensions.TextBox Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnhttps://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_InputExtensions_TextBox_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_Object_)
- [How to create a readonly text using html helper in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153912/how-to-create-a-readonly-text-using-html-helper-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [HTML  readonly Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Comment: consegui! obrigada!

Comment: Se for util assinale como resposta da sua pergunta @BeatriceBenetti